# How can I point one domain to different websites

Tags: html, dns, web-hosting

I have two pages built with two website builders. One with Wix.com, and the other using kickofflabs.com. I want to host both of the pages to my domain and hosting. I can only host one now, how can I host two? I used CNAME in pointing on of the websites.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing would be to create one or two subdomains, and point each one of those at the appropriate hosting. For instance, `page1.domain.com` would point to your `wix.com` page, and `page2.domain.com` would point to your `kickofflabs.com` page.

See this SO question: [Subdomain on different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189552/subdomain-on-different-host)

To be honest, you'd probably be better off in the long run just using one website builder.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an a record to point your domain to server. and you should config that server to receive that request