# Subdomain displaying contents of a specific website located on a different host

Tags: subdomain

Duplicate of this question:

[Subdomain on different host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189552/subdomain-on-different-host)

which was correctly answered with this:

"You just need to add an "A" record in the DNS manager on Godaddy. In that "A" record put your IP from dreamhost (the server itself)"

with one difference:

What if there are 10 websites on Dreamhost and i would like to point at a specific website, for example trains.com ?

Instead of creating an A record, i created a CNAME record for my subdomain pointing to trains.com

Yet after propagation, i still get the same result. My subdomain still displays the default plesk page of the Dreamhost server, not trains.com.

Comment: Keep in mind that DNS updates can take up to 48 Hours

Comment: DNS update has already taken place. As stated, instead of seeing the default page of the subdomain, i now see the default page of the server the subdomain is pointing to. After setting the CNAME, it should specifically resolve the contents of trains.com, should it not ?